# C++ New up std::vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stdvector

I have an Animal class. The `DiffClass`, has pointers to the `Animal` class. I am trying to work out how to properly use `std::vector` instead of `new` as it means I don't have to delete the memory myself. I don't understand why the vector does not recognise the function in the `Animal` class. Any clue?

```
class Animal
{
 void display(); //displays one animal
}

class DiffClass
{
 public:
    void someFunctionToSetUpVector()
    {
     AnimalPointer = new std::vector<Animal>;
      for ( int i = 0; i <AnimalPointer.size(); i++)
      {
        AnimalPointer[i].display(); // does not work, can't find function
      }
    }
 private:
    std::vector<Animal>* AnimalPointer = 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no way this code could possibly ever get compiled, by any C++ compiler. The blatant compilation error is too obvious. Please post real code, not make-believe code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: He's asking about a compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AnimalPointer` is a pointer to `vector`, so `AnimalPointer[i]` is a vector, not a `Animal` and call `display()` on it won't work. For the similar reason `AnimalPointer.size()` won't work either.

You don't need to use pointer to `vector`, just

```
class DiffClass
{
public:
    void someFunctionToSetUpVector()
    {
        animals.push_back(Animal()); // add one Animal
        // add more Animals...

        for (int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++)
        {
            animals[i].display();
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Animal> animals;
};
```